# Form won't submit within div

Tags: html

I cannot seem to figure out why this form will not submit and post to the page I have directed it to. When I click the submit button (called send form) it does absolutely nothing.

```
<div class="form-wrapper clearfix">
<form action="mail-sent.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-contact             email-form" id="form1">
<div class="inputs-wrapper">
<input class="form-name validate-required" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="name">
<input class="form-email validate-required validate-email" type="text" name="email"   placeholder="Your Email Address">
<textarea class="form-message validate-required" name="message" placeholder="Your Message">        </textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="send-form" value="Send Form">
<div class="form-success">
<span class="text-white">Message sent - Thanks for your enquiry</span>
</div>
<div class="form-error">
<span class="text-white">Please complete all fields correctly</span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript bit:

```
// Contact form
$('form.email-form').submit(function (e) {
// return false so form submits through jQuery rather than reloading page.
if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); else e.returnValue = false;

console.log('We have a submission...');
var thisForm        = $(this).closest('.email-form'),
error           = 0,
originalError   = thisForm.attr('original-error');

if (typeof originalError !== typeof undefined && originalError !== false) {
thisForm.find('.form-error').text(originalError); 
}


$(thisForm).find('.validate-required').each(function(){
if($(this).val() === ''){
$(this).addClass('field-error');
error = 1;
}
else{
$(this).removeClass('field-error');
}
});

$(thisForm).find('.validate-email').each(function(){
if(!(/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test($(this).val()))){
$(this).addClass('field-error');
error = 1;
}
else{
$(this).removeClass('field-error');
}
});


if (error === 1){
$(this).closest('.email-form').find('.form-error').fadeIn(200);
}
else{
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "mail/mail.php",
data: thisForm.serialize(),
success: function (response) {
// Swiftmailer always sends back a number representing numner of emails sent.
// If this is numeric (not Swift Mailer error text) AND greater than 0 then show success     message.
if($.isNumeric(response)){
if(parseInt(response) > 0){
thisForm.find('.form-success').fadeIn(1000);
thisForm.find('.form-error').fadeOut(1000);
setTimeout(function(){ thisForm.find('.form-success').fadeOut(500); }, 5000);
}
}
// If error text was returned, put the text in the .form-error div and show it.
else{
// Keep the current error text in a data attribute on the form
thisForm.find('.form-error').attr('original-error', thisForm.find('.form-error').text());
// Show the error with the returned error text.
thisForm.find('.form-error').text(response).fadeIn(1000);
thisForm.find('.form-success').fadeOut(1000);
}
}
});
}
return false;
});


});

$(window).load(function(){

"use strict";
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong here. Perhaps you've some Javascript somewhere doing [**`preventDefault()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault), or hijacking the button press.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3o74bxnp/

Comment: Looks like you're relying on AJAX or Javascript to submit your form.  It should still be reloading the page though by the look of the HTML that you have provided... unless your Javascript is stopping it

Comment: Works in a fiddle, the classes look like the form is bound to a library, thats likely where the issue lies

Comment: Aha, I took a guess and found something related to the preventDefault() you mentioned. Not sure how I can post code here though as there isn't enough characters?

Comment: I edited my first post and added the js code there. Is that where the problem is?